# Is DynamoDBContext Thread Safe?

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I know that the `AmazonDynamoDBClient` is thread-safe and I can init a singleton when my app starts and keep using it throughout the apps lifetime.

Does the same apply to `DynamoDBContext`?

Comment: How do you know it's thread safe? I tried find official documentation stating just that but cannot seem to find any.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the DynamoDBContext is thread-safe.

It also maintains a number of caches (like table descriptions) which are populated from DynamoDB, so it's best to keep an instance around for as long as possible. This will help avoid making extra service calls to repopulate the caches.

Comment: Here is some official source of info https://aws.amazon.com/articles/2790257258340776