# async method in asp.net causing requests to never finish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, amazon-dynamodb

I have an async asp.net mvc 4 action that seemingly works fine.

Debugging through it works as expected.

The issue is when this is out in production, after awhile the requests start to pile up and nothing is getting processed.  This sounds to me like some sort of deadlock, but I'm not sure where the problem is.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    //some work
    var user = PopulateUser();
    try
    {
        await DynamoUtil.WriteToDynamoAsync(user);
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    { 
        //standard log4net logging
        _log.Error("Error writing to dynamo", x);
    }

    //.. some more work

    return Redirect(url);
}
```

My `WriteToDynamoAsync` method is something similar to this

```
public static class DynamoUtil
{
    //..

    //instantiated in static constructor
    private static DynamoDBContext _context;

    public static async Task WriteToDynamoAsync(User user)
    {
        try
        {
            var batch = _context.CreateBatchWrite<User>();
            batch.AddPutItem(user);
            await batch.ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error("Error executing batch", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing to note, is if I remove the first `await` on the `WriteToDynamoAsync` method, it works fine.  Everything keeps chugging along.  The issue with doing that is I want to actually make sure the item gets written to Dynamo, and I want the exception logged if it doesn't.

Can anyone see a problem with the above, or have any suggestions?

Also, I have tried with and without the `ConfigureAwait`, that doesn't seem to change any outcome.

I haven't been able to reproduce the undesired behavior debugging, but when it's live and getting hit with 4 to 5 requests per second, the whole website will stop working within a minute or two.

Comment: is `_context.CreateBatchWrite<User>();` thread safe? If you are calling the same class from multiple threads in to stuff like Entity Framework you can cause deadlocks.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain ``The DynamoDBContext object is thread-safe`` from Amazon docs https://aws.amazon.com/articles/2790257258340776, so I assume it is.  I have not peeked at the source of that method though.

Comment: [Is DynamoDBContext Thread Safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308293/is-dynamodbcontext-thread-safe)

Comment: It's going to be hard to debug this. Was this code synchronous you could just pause the (remote) debugger and see what the threads are doing. Try to convert this to synchronous code for testing purposes and remote debug.

Comment: you can also log into your aws console and make sure that your requests to dynamodb table are not getting throttled.

Comment: @ErbenMo that was my thought too, but we checked and are no where near our put limits to be throttled

Comment: Did you try to convert WriteToDynamoAsync to a non static method, just to be sure? Also, I guess batch.ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) should result in some http(s) request - did you try to use fiddler to see if requests were even sent? Because maybe, just maybe, you don't get any response from the server...?

Comment: @KyleGobel : I'm getting the same issue. did you get the solution?

Comment: @RealSteel unfortunately no, and have seen the same thing happen in other apps.  At the time I switched everything to using the synchronous methods and that solved the issue for us.  In short I just gave up :(

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are already logging any potential exceptions in `WriteToDynamoAsync` itself, so why do it in `Index` as well?

Second, your problem is most probably that you have way more concurrent request in production than in development, and that your DB connection is much slower in the former case (in the latter it's probably on the same machine even).

Thirdly, don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in `Index` because you need it to return to the exact same request thread (it's not static).

And last, you will have to either make your production DB connection faster, or somehow lower its usage (make fewer DB calls).

Also, don't remove `await` from `WriteToDynamoAsync` if it's business critical, otherwise it may not finish if app domain recycles, and you won't even know it.